# adding instances in eureka sever

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix, netflix-ribbon

```
server.port=1013
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:1000/eureka
eureka.instance.instanceId= ${spring.application.name}:${random.int}
```

I'm using the default port 1013 in producer. How do I add another instance in netflix ribbon so that load balancing can pick any of port?

Comment: If you manually adding hostnames **in** ribbon, then you do not need Eureka.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. 
deployed same micro-service with different port and different name . then it will register to eureka using ribbon. then load balancer will pick any of instances.

Comment: Eureka does not need ribbon at all. There is no dependency of Eureka on ribbon. The hostname used by Eureka comes from `eureka.instance.hostname`. If you do not provide this, then hostname provided by `NetworkInterfaces` class of Java is used by Eureka. You have made wrong assumptions in both your question and answer. Please read the docs and update both question and answer.